# problems with libkdtree++ (kdtree)

Tags: kdtree

I am a student trying to use kdtree with libkdtree++ on linux 86*64. ./configure goes smooth, though sudo make install fails

```
cd . && /bin/sh /home/preetigupta25/kdtree-project/nvmd-libkdtree-7bb7e83/missing --run aclocal-1.10

/home/preetigupta25/kdtree-project/nvmd-libkdtree-7bb7e83/missing: line 54: aclocal-1.10: command not found

WARNING:     `aclocal-1.10' is missing on your system. 



/home/preetigupta25/kdtree-project/nvmd-libkdtree-7bb7e83/missing: line 54: automake-1.10: command not found
WARNING: `automake-1.10' is missing on your system. 

cd . && /bin/sh /home/preetigupta25/kdtree-project/nvmd-libkdtree-7bb7e83/missing --run autoconf
configure.ac:10:  error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

make: *** [configure] Error 1

but when I run it again it gives a different problem

[preetigupta25@dhalsim nvmd-libkdtree-7bb7e83]$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for preetigupta25:
/bin/sh ./config.status --recheck

running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
./configure: line 2082: syntax error near unexpected token `-Wall'
./configure: line 2082: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(-Wall -Werror)'
make: *** [config.status] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will have a more recent automake version - 1.11 I guess.

You will have to change that in `configure`:

```
am__api_version='1.11'
```

You have to do it before you invoke `configure` the first time.